# Setting allowdrop to true cause memory leak in .net application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, memory-leaks

My application uses `allowdrop=true` in windows form to be able to do drag and drop, along with that it has many custom events. When I ran the profile I found most of the object is help back by droptarget object.

Please let me know how to fix it.

I read it somewhere setting it back to false resolves this, but my control is loaded in the memory in another container and even when I close, it turns out not removed from the memory. I just get constructor event first time when it shows and there after it stays in the memory even if we close it.

So I don't get any other event and no events are performed on it and I continue to see memory leaks when i close and open my control from container. Let me know how to fix it. I get dispose event only when I close container..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is: **Don't use your `Form` as drop destination, use a small panel like container that toggles the `AllowDrop` property.**

In some cases the hack below has solved the problem.

```
void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    //reset the AllowDrop and call GC to collect memory
    AllowDrop = false;
    GC.Collect();
    GC.Collect();
    AllowDrop = true;
}
```

Comment: Can you link to the bug report?

Comment: hi can you provide some reference document where t says its known issue.

Comment: I can not find the bug report, I have edited the answer but I remember I read it :) @dsolimano

Comment: Oy, I hate when that happens.